# What about a denomination-survey tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, denominations

The majority of questions with the [denomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination) tag ask which denominations believe or practice X. There are some however which consider denominations as a category. Here are a couple of examples:

- [What are the general categories of benefits of being part of a denomination?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60606/6071)
- [What is the difference between a denomination and a movement?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59467/6071)
- [Was Christianity intended to have denominations?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2429/6071) (should be closed btw)
- [Seeking a graphic or flowchart of the history of the formation of Christian denominations](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/56203/6071)
- [What is the source of the count of 40000 denominations, and how are they classified?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63368/6071)

I propose that we switch to using a [denomination-survey](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination-survey) tag. That would more accurately describe what these questions are. The few that are not could be tagged [denominations](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denominations) (I prefer the -s although that doesn't really matter, but if a mod was feeling generous they could set up a synonym after all of this is finished).

As there are so many, I think it would be best if a mod could **merge** [denomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination) into [denomination-survey](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination-survey) **without** making a synonym. If this is done then we can manually retag the small number which are not survey questions.

Comment: So in this scheme, where would your four examples end up?  And where would the "which denominations believe X" questions go?

Comment: @Nathaniel the which denominations believe X would be denomination-survey, and the four examples would be denominations

Comment: @Nathaniel Any thoughts on this now?

Comment: One other way that this tag is used is for questions about specific but relatively minor denominations, like https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/52353/21576 or https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46524/21576.  Do you envision those keeping the denomination tag until such time as those denominations get their own tags?

Comment: @Nathaniel no, I don't think that's a useful tagging

Comment: Does this tag suggest that the OP is seeking a single answer that surveys the beliefs of all denominations associated with the assertion, or does it seek a series of answers, at worst one for each applicable denomination? (I am rarely satisfied by single-answer solutions as the respondent is rarely conversant in the theology of all associated denominations, resulting in two-dimensional and even minimalist summaries of those denominations the respondent has not mastered.)

Comment: @JBH I think in practice either have been okay, everyone can answer with as many denominations as they know of that meet the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in favor of change like this.  Let me attempt a concrete usage suggestion:

- [denomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination) is used for the concept of denominations, and all five of the questions in the OP would fit in it

  - [What are the general categories of benefits of being part of a denomination?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60606/21576)
  - [What is the difference between a denomination and a movement?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59467/21576)
  - [Is Calvary Chapel a denomination?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/45786/21576)
- [denomination-survey](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination-survey) is used for identifying denominations or traditions that meet some criteria (beliefs, practices, etc.)

  - [What denominations of Christianity forbid meat from strangled animals?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63746/21576)
  - [Are there any Christian Restorationist denominations that believe their establishment was the fulfillment of Biblical prophecy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/55368/21576)
  - [Are there any non-pacifist traditions that object to military chaplaincy?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41504/21576)
- [comparative-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-christianity) is used for comparing the beliefs/practices/etc. of two or more denominations or traditions

  - [How do different Protestant denominations view the relationship between Israel and the Church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/44260/21576)
  - [What is the difference in doctrine between the Pentecostal church and the Assemblies of God church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/52835/21576)
  - [What is the Difference Between ROCOR-MP and ROCOR-A (ROCA)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/26335/21576)

Note that there are numerous other questions in [denomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination) that do not fit into any of these categories.  Two categories jump out at me:

- Questions about particular, relatively minor denomination

  - [How prevalent is the group known as the 2x2's?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/52353/21576)
- Questions seeking an overview of what all Christian denominations teach on a particular subject.

  - [What are the differences between cherubim and seraphim?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/35632/21576)

I'd remove [denomination](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination) from such questions, and not replace it.

Comment: As I wrote this, I realized that perhaps `comparative-christianity` could be used on all our overviews of doctrine questions, but let's handle that separately from this discussion.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're right about the tag being a poor descriptor of what's truly being asked. But I'd lean towards considering [denomination-survey](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination-survey) as a meta-tag, (i.e. it describes what the question is, not what is being asked about)

I prefer [comparative-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-christianity) when I'm asking those kinds of questions since that seems more like a genuine field of study.

I think we should do the opposite of what you're asking then, use the [denominations](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denominations) for *these* questions where the subject actually is denominations. And re-tag most of the [denominations](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denominations) with [comparative-christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-christianity).

Comment: Well, better IMO to have a tag that accurate describes what it's being used for than one which doesn't just because it's a meta tag. Comparative-christianity doesn't really seem that similar, because these questions aren't asking for you to compare between the denominations.

Comment: I initially didn't even think of this as a meta tag, but I see where you are coming from.  Still, I think this is more of a "meta-ish" tag like biblical-basis, for example, as opposed to a straight meta tag like homework or overview.  "Denomination-survey" does identify the type of question, but it seems to me that it also provides a bit of information about the subject of the question.

Comment: This is a great example question for the comparative-christianity tag: [What are the main differences between the Catholic Popes and the Mormon Prophets?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63482/6071) It's nothing like these denomination survey questions. I don't see why it would be better to move them to the comparative tag.

Comment: Though thank you for pointing out that many denomination survey questions are already misusing (IMO, though also according to the tag description) the comparative-christianity tag.