# How to scope overview questions

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

This is about this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90922/22319) (and a bit about [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90517/22319)), which while I think are good questions to ask, they are not IMO a good fit for this site as they are too broad. SE sites are for finding [real answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) not a bunch of answers from different perspectives (I'm referencing as if an answer gets 5 answers from different denominations which seems to be what OP in first example wants/likes `If this attracts answers which show the official position of the large mainstream denominations, I am already happy`; a question on stackoverflow asking how multiple languages would address something would be shut down pretty quick-IMO these are similar questions)

Meta posts about overview questions:

- [Denomination-survey](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6537/what-about-a-denomination-survey-tag/6595#6595) tag (while not indicated this could potentially be applied, but this doesn't look like a fix)

  > is used for identifying denominations or traditions that meet some criteria (beliefs, practices, etc.)

  Similarly:

  > comparative-christianity is used for comparing the beliefs/practices/etc. of two or more denominations or traditions
- [Overview questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/871/22319)

  > 2. What different beliefs about Z are there and who holds them?

  > Example ② is different. It might be too broad if Z is a big topic and there are 50 views on it, but if it is a reasonably focused issue and there are only a handful of positions, somebody who is knowledgeable on the issue (we are a site for experts) could step in and provide a well rounded overview such as "The major two views are X which states xxx and Y which states yyy. Several variants of X exist around the side issue W. Position X is usually held in churches Q and R, while S churches official hold to position Y. The theologians who first wrote about each position where G and H..." and so on. Without defending one view as correct, they could show what the various views are held by profession Christian groups. It is easy to judge with some objectivity whether an answer to this kind of question is helpful and covers all the bases even without being an expert in the individual views.

The posts in question don't seem to limit what denomination they are looking for and has multiple points they'd like addressed. The second post I attempted to start a community wiki so multiple denominations could be addressed in the answer but as pointed out in the comments `The format you are trying to start is going to be hard to read and unclear` and no one else edited the wiki.

So my question(s)

- Are these on topic and if so why/how?

  - If SE is searching for finding real answers it would seem community wikis are the way to go for overview questions of this type (I feel it rare that anyone actually has an in-depth understanding of multiple denominations-I have seen multiple users claiming to be familiar with my denomination yet have it misrepresented by them in an answer, I feel this could probably be applied to other users/denominations as well)
  - if community wiki is not the way to go, is the answer that covers most of the answer (according to OP) correct even if it omits other denominations or doesn't address each point for each denomination?
  - Is there a way to edit the questions to keep the spirit of the question but make them more focused/on topic